# Area of non-right angleTriangle is given, rise/run given, no sidelength is known, calculate triangle height.

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

[image]

I have a triangle of $600m^2 $ area, I do not have any lengths of this triangle, I only have the rise/run of both sides that are not sitting on the x-axis, and the area, can I find the height given the relation it has with the angles of the triangle?

Angles of this triangle in degrees are $23.94, 23.12, 132.94$ I calculated this by
calculating $\tan^{-1}$ of the both slopes (rise/run)
slope1=$0.444$
slope2=$0.429$
(image provided is a rough similarity)

How would I approach this question?

Comment: If you are asking if the dimensions are all determined by the data, then yes.  The triangle is determined up to similarity by the three angles, and then knowing the area specifies it exactly.  One quick thing might be to just set one side (the base, I suppose) to $1$ and solving for everything.  Then scale appropriately to match the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area is
$$\mathcal{A}=\frac{1}{2}CD(AD+DB).$$
We know the slopes, the angles are not necessary. It suffices to realize that the slopes are $$\frac{CD}{AD}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{CD}{DB},$$ respectively. Then
$$AD=0.444\times CD, DB=0.429\times CD.$$   Putting this and the known value of the area into the first equation you obtain the height.

Comment: Thank you very much mate, very grateful. I got the answer, but it was AD=CD/0.444 and DB=CD/0.429 I wouldn't have been able to do it without your help though.